# Google chrome doesn't open multiple mail clients

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, data-binding, mailto

I have the following code in which I am trying to open multiple mailclient
It works in Firefox but dont work in Chrome

```
<button class="button">Open Email</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').on('click',function(){
       window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here";
       window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject2&body=message%20goes%20here";
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle to it](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ws7/1/)

Anyone knows whats the reason behind this , or is there any other technique to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gaboom/h81qov5g/

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gaboom/h81qov5g/

Answer (score 2):

Chrome allows only one opened window per user action. If opening new browsers window was the issue, you could tell the popup blocker to allow it, but this is not possible when launching email windows. You could either require two user actions (e.g. two buttons) or you could make a web based mail form to do the same thing (if you're using the mail client of tracing purposes, just make it send a copy to yourself.

Comment: I've just tried some things and I got it working in a pretty ugly way. You create a page which launches the mailto: handler. When you call this page multiple times using an iframe it will launch multiple mailto: windows. I don't think it's a good idea to rely on methods like this is like a workaround for Chrome's usability guidelines.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/C2LXD/14/ (I put a dialogue in there only because you would get stuck in a loop)

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: Couldn't find any documentation on this subject, so this is just by trial and error. It might have changed the last 2,5 years though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open multiple links you shouldn't use `window.location.href`, it opens link in current window and you cant really have more than one link opened in one window. You should use `window.open(your_url)` for that, but beware, it will create popup windows.

From a browser perspective `mailto` is a link like any other, so assigning it to `window.location.href` twice in a row is like fast-clicking two links in a page, browser will process only one of them.

And the last, code from your question not working even in FF if you use browser based mail client, like gmail.

Comment: not sure what are you talking about, it is not a redirection, its simple mail client using mailto, I am not trying to open seperate page..

Comment: it works in FF and opens your Microsoft Outlook but dont work in chrome

Comment: I even tried to add some time elapse between these but that didn't worked

Comment: @user1765876 I've updated my answer, hope you'll see my point now. As for that part about `X-Frame-Options`I don't know why, but I thought you are talking about gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You could supply 2 links for the user tp open the email clients manually, you could also open the client, refresh the page (indicating something on the url for the second one) and then open the second one?